# How to authenticate myself in Postman using API Key with Rscript

Tags: r, api, postman

I'm trying to create an API connection with Postman, but i need to authenticate myself using **Type = API Key**. these are my credentials[image]

My problem is because i don't know hot to add that cretentials to my Rscript to be able to access, this is my current code

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)

# Settings 
.proxy <- list(url = "gbiss-l-ss31.int.dir.witowa.com",
               user =  "svc-g-gad",
               pwd = "5vcGBgaGaSrf",
               port = 8090,
               Header = list(Key <- 'X-EDS-USER', 
                              Value <- 'B6E6685F-DB0C-438A-983F')
               )

format_url_data <- function(x){

  raw <- httr::GET(url = x,
                   httr::use_proxy(
                     url = .proxy$url,
                     port = .proxy$port,
                     username = .proxy$user,
                     password = .proxy$pwd
                   )
  )

  raw <- intToUtf8(raw$content)

  jsonlite::fromJSON(raw)

}

############################ FOR FF  (Don't change anything) ##################################################################
#Define Url
# Define Url

basehttr <- 'https://iat.eds.gateway-api.willistowerswatson.com/Clients/Search?query='
endhttr <- 'APPLE'
endhttr_backup <- endhttr
endhttr <- URLencode(endhttr)
url <- glue::glue('{basehttr}{endhttr}')

# Get the information and convert to df
dt <- tryCatch( {
  dt <- purrr::map(url, ~format_url_data(.))},
  error = function(  error_condition ) {

    basehttr <- "https://qa.eds.gateway-api.willistowerswatson.com/gateway-api/Clients/Search?query="
    endhttr <- 'APPLE'
    endhttr_backup <- endhttr
    endhttr <- URLencode(endhttr)
    url <- glue::glue('{basehttr}{endhttr}')

    dt <- purrr::map(url, ~format_url_data(.))
  }
)
A <- dt %>% as.list.data.frame()            
B <- ldply (A, data.frame)

Data <- B %>%
  drop_na(name) %>% as.data.frame()

Data$Name <- gsub("[^[:alnum:][:blank:]?&/\\-]", "", Data$Name)
```

When i run my code  get an Authentication error
Could you help me to connect with Postman with that credentials?
**Thanks**

Comment: I'm getting a 403 with both postman and httr.

Comment: Maybe is because there is an private account, you need to be in the VPN to access for that sever, my concern is about add the Key and the Value in R, for a general authentication in Postman using R

Comment: If postman works, then you should be able to use `GET(url = x, add_headers('X-EDS-USER' = 'B6E6685F-DB0C-438A-983F'), use_proxy(url = .proxy$url,
                     port = .proxy$port,
                     username = .proxy$user,
                     password = .proxy$pwd
                   ))`

Comment: That works very well, Thanks Allan !!